# Get RadioButtons By Row - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to get the radiobuttons row by row, but this query gets all the radios in the table.

```
function Check() {
var table = document.getElementById("tblMain");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
var arrRadios = new Array();
arrRadios = this.document.getElementsByName("radio");
var len = arrRadios.length; //it gives 6 here, when I want 3
}
}

<table id="tblMain">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" />1)
                <input type="radio" name="radio" />2)
                <input type="radio" name="radio" />3)                
            </td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" />1)
                <input type="radio" name="radio" />2)
                <input type="radio" name="radio" />3)                
            </td>            
        </tr>
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" 
      OnClientClick="return Check()" value="click"/>        
    </table>
```

Please suggest a solution by Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do this:

```
  var table = document.getElementById("tblMain");
  for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
      var arrRadios = new Array();
      arrRadios = document.querySelectorAll('#tblMain tr:nth-child(' + (i+1) + ') input[type=radio]');
      var len = arrRadios.length; 
  }
```

This might not work, if your browser isn't a reasonably current version.

Answer (score 0):

Althought there is different solution. Here is one close to what you have started

```
function Check() {
var table = document.getElementById("tblMain");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
var arrRadios = new Array();
arrRadios = this.document.getElementsByName("radio_"+i);
var len = arrRadios.length; //it gives 6 here, when I want 3
}
}

<table id="tblMain">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="radio_0" />1)
                <input type="radio" name="radio_0" />2)
                <input type="radio" name="radio_0" />3)                
            </td>            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="radio_1" />1)
                <input type="radio" name="radio_1" />2)
                <input type="radio" name="radio_1" />3)                
            </td>            
        </tr>
    <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" 
      OnClientClick="return Check()" value="click"/>        
    </table>
```

There is two changes : rename the radio with by added _ + the number of the row
Then il your for loop add the same thing to call the radio on the row.

Comment: Thank you. that works but the rows are dynamic in my case and cant be named such

Comment: Add the _# while creating them.